# Replace ViewController

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to change between two View Controllers. Both of the ViewControllers inherit from CenterViewController. The code below is to add one ViewController (CertificatenViewController) to the stack:

```
centerViewController = CertificatenViewController(nibName: "CertificatenViewController", bundle: nil)
    centerViewController.delegate = self
centerNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
    view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
    addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)

    centerNavigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

This happens in the viewDidLoad and in the same class I have a switch statement to check which View has to be loaded, something like this:

```
        switch menuItem.getNibname() {
    case "CertificatenViewController":
        print(menuItem.getNibname())

        centerViewController = CertificatenViewController(nibName: menuItem.getNibname(), bundle: nil)
        centerViewController.delegate = self

    case "SettingsViewController":
        print(menuItem.getNibname())

        centerViewController = SettingsViewController(nibName: menuItem.getNibname(), bundle: nil)
        centerViewController.delegate = self      

    default: break

    }
```

I don't know exactly what the problem is, but it seems to be that the view is not reloaded. I have tried popViewControllerAnimated but this is not working. Maybe you can help me solving this problem.

**Solution:**

```
    func changeView(menuItem: MenuItem){

    self.centerNavigationController.viewControllers.removeAll()


    switch menuItem.getNibname() {
    case "CertificatenViewController":
        print(menuItem.getNibname())

        self.centerNavigationController.pushViewController(self.centerViewController, animated: false)

    case "SettingsViewController":
        print(menuItem.getNibname())

        self.centerNavigationController.pushViewController(self.settingsViewController, animated: false)

    case "MessagesViewController":
        print(menuItem.getNibname())

        self.centerNavigationController.pushViewController(self.messagesViewController, animated: false)

    default: break

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by **change** between two View Controller? If you mean to push or modally present a next view controller what you did is not correct. The answer below show you how to present a view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this is NOT the way to present view controllers:

```
view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)

centerNavigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Just remove that code.

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but something like

```
self.presentViewController(centerNavigationController, animated: true, complettion: nil)
```

is typical.  This makes the current view controller show the navigation controller (usually just on top of itself).  Then the nav-controller will show the root you set up inside of itself (so the centerViewController).

When you want to get rid of it, you call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` on the view controller instance that did the presenting.  It dismisses the navigation controller (do not call dismiss on the navigation controller)

Later, when you want to replace, where you do this:

```
    centerViewController = CertificatenViewController(nibName: menuItem.getNibname(), bundle: nil)
    centerViewController.delegate = self
```

Add:

```
    centerNavigationController.setViewControllers([centerViewController], animated: true)
```